# C++ Private inheritance with classes

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance

Cannot figure out how to get the data from class Main. Please any advice will be appreciated.
Needs to print the same as Main would but via Child.
**I know there are better ways** this is how my teacher has asked it to be done. Yet I can't find anything explaining the process online or in the textbook.

// Program to use a class **Child** which inherited from **Main** using **private** inheritance

```
class Main{
    public:
        void setName(string n){name = n;}
        string getName() {return name;}

        void print() {cout << "Some dudes name: " << getName() << endl;}
        
    private:
        string name;
};

class Child: private Main{
    public:
        void setName(string n){Main::setName;}
        string getName(){return Main::getName();}

        void print(){...}
};
```

Comment: `Main::setName;` has no effect. Did you mean `Main::setName(n);`?

Comment: You have used three different patterns in your three methods (use the function name, invoke the function, and something redacted via `...`). Have you tried being consistent? Use the same pattern in all three methods. With at most three patterns, it takes only three trials to see if any of them work.

Comment: @JaMiT Cheers for the input. What do you mean by three different patterns? I am rather new to this so only following the layout the teacher has taught which confuses the sht out of me. Any chance you can explain the patterns so that I can do this better?

Comment: `getName` is correct, just do the same for the other 2 functions

Comment: @CSstudent The first pattern is **`function_name(parameters){Main::function_name;}`** which you use in `setName`. To apply this pattern to the other functions, replace `function_name` by the name of the function and `parameters` by the applicable parameters. *For example, to applying this pattern to `getName` gives `getName(){Main::getName;}`.* The second pattern is **`function_name(parameters){Main::function_name(arguments);}`** which you use in `getName`. *For example, to applying this pattern to `setName` gives `setName(string n){Main::setName(n);}`.* The third pattern is hidden to me.

Comment: @CSstudent If you did not notice the different patterns you used (it would not be surprising if it was accidental), take a look at the code in your question. Focus on the syntax highlighting. Notice that `Main::setName` without parentheses is highlighted differently than `Main::getName()` with parentheses. Sometimes programming aids point out errors that you otherwise would have not noticed.

Comment: Thanks for all the help got it working!
REALLLY appreciate it!!